# Hartl's Rails tutorial - false with "authenticated?" (activation_token)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

**Dear Colleagues.**

I'm doing a Hartl's Railstutorial and encountered a problem, I can not solve. Every step I make according to the tutorial.

**Description of the problem:**

When doing exercise, *"Using the generalized authenticated? Method from Listing 11.26, verify That the user is authenticated According to remember both the token and the activation token."*

Where the correct result should look like:

```
>> User.authenticated (: remember, user.remember_token)
=> True
>> User.authenticated (: activation, user.activation_token)
=> True
```

Meanwhile, in my case, it is:

```
user = User.create(name: "Test User", email: "test@example.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER(?) LIMIT ?  [["email", "test@example.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "email", "created_at", "updated_at", "password_digest", "activation_digest") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Test User"], ["email", "test@example.com"], ["created_at", 2017-02-26 20:36:50 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-02-26 20:36:50 UTC], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$caQcP8VAQJaUwaFQwOt4j.RadReeSllF5TBEwbvuu1D08.A/LPOlC"], ["activation_digest", "$2a$10$q2aPIqOaNWlZstIsKnCjbev7DqC2UXkRoNTMO3XAvYj3tIcVG40Gy"]]
   (41.1ms)  commit transaction
=> #<User id: 104, name: "Test User", email: "test@example.com", created_at: "2017-02-26 20:36:50", updated_at: "2017-02-26 20:36:50", password_digest: "$2a$10$caQcP8VAQJaUwaFQwOt4j.RadReeSllF5TBEwbvuu1D...", remember_digest: nil, admin: false, activation_digest: "$2a$10$q2aPIqOaNWlZstIsKnCjbev7DqC2UXkRoNTMO3XAvYj...", activated: false, activated_at: nil>


>> User.authenticated (: activation, user.activation_token)
=> False
```

As a result, **I can not make the user activation at a later stage**.

Does anyone of you is able to give me the reason?

My files:

**user_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user, only: :destroy

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.account_activation(@user).deliver_now
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account." 
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])    
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated" 
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end 
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, 
                                 :password_confirmation,
                                 :admin)
  end

  # Before filters

  # Confirms a logged-in user

  def logged_in_user
    unless logged_in?
      store_location
      flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
      redirect_to login_url
    end
  end

  # Confirms the correct user.
  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
  end 

  # Confirms an admin user.
  def admin_user
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
  end 
end
```

**user.erb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token

  before_save   :downcase_email
  before_create :create_activation_digest

  validates :name,  presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255},
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX},
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password,  presence: true, length: {minimum: 6}, allow_nil: true

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                BCrypt::Engine.cost
                                                BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end

  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

  private

  # Convertsemail to all lower-case
  def downcase_email
    email.downcase!   
  end

  # Create the token and digest
  def create_activation_digest
    self.activation_token  = User.new_token
    self.activation_digest = User.digest(:activation_token) 
  end

end
```

**account_activations_controller.rb**

```
class AccountActivationsController < ApplicationController

    def edit
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if user && !user.activated? && user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])
      user.update_attribute(:activated,    true)
      user.update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)
      log_in user
      flash[:success] = "Account activated!"
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Invalid activation link"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. To help us dig into what's happening here... can you please provide us a link to the section of Hartl's tutorial that you are working on? I've googled for the quote you have at the top (starting: `"Using the generalized authenticated? Method`) and the only page I got from google was this one...

Comment: Some minor questions (might be just typos rather than a real error) about this line of code: `User.authenticated (: activation, user.activation_token)` 1) are you really typing `authenticated` or `authenticated?`  (the latter is the real name of the method - it needs the question-mark) 2) there should be no whitespace between the `:` and the name of the symbol eg `:activation` not `: activation` 3) likewise no space between the method-name and the parenthesis eg `authenticated(` not `authenticated (`

Comment: 4) why are you calling `authenticated?` on `User` instead of `user` ? this is an instance method, not a class method. Surely you should be using: `user.authenticated?(:activation, user.activation_token)` or similar... ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Link to lesson: [Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation)

The afternoon will verify my code and I will refer to your comments. Thanks!

Comment: I checked. Responding to questions 1-3: whitespaces and lack of "?" It was the result of a failed copying to the SO.

I still can not solve my problem. Please help.
`irb(main):005:0> user.authenticated?(:remember, user.remember_token)
=> true
irb(main):006:0> user.authenticated?(:activation, user.activation_token)
=> false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I had an error in the file **user.rb**

**I had:**

```
  def create_activation_digest
    self.activation_token  = User.new_token
    self.activation_digest = User.digest(:activation_token) 
  end
```

**should be:** (activation_token without ":")

```
  def create_activation_digest
    self.activation_token  = User.new_token
    self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token) 
  end
```

I present a solution, because it can be useful for someone.

Thank you for the advice.